# Connecting to an API offered by a Company

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, wsdl

I currently have an internal system that I need to link up to an API offered by a company.  I am not looking for hand-holding on this, I really need to understand where and how to get started really.

Here is the developer resource for the API I am looking to work with:
http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/Postal_Address_Verification

Further, my systems are currently in ASP/ASP.NET & SQL, and I'm familiar with VB so I would rather stay that direction instead of C#.

Can I get some direction on how to tackle this?  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Have you already checked out http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/PAVv3_VB ? In terms of linking it to an internal system, I'd strongly recommend you set up some sort of staging environment *off the main network* to prevent direct access to your software/databases from the outside world (and to otherwise prevent data loss) - connecting via an encrypted connection is also highly recommended. Depending on what you're doing, you'll want to look into PCI-DSS compliance - https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/ - since it sounds like some user data could potentially be exposed.

Comment: Basically this API simply verifies and corrects delivery addresses from the production DB to the USPS DB.  The application will be PCI-DSS compliant in the end, as it will go through a cert process from home office, but I have to come up with the core functionality prior to all that.

Comment: I checked that link prior to posting, and I do understand how it is operating - I suppose I'm missing how my system connects back through the API.  I'm assuming I create some type of service or application residing service that takes care of the communication and contains the various fields and error corrections from the WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to add a Service Reference in your project.  Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and choose "Add Service Reference...".  Copy the WSDL URL (from the documentation page you linked) into the address box and click Go. More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Use "WCFpav" as the Namespace to match the examples.
You should be able to use the C# example, just change the syntax for VB.Net (or use a converter, but it's a simple exercise).

Note: the Add Service Reference wizard is available in VS2008 and VS2010.

Comment: Steve - Thanks a ton for this direction, this really helped a lot.  I can now see the functions and begin to understand how to make calls and responses accordingly.  I'm going to mark this as answered at this point, but I'm sure I'll have more questions unrelated to beginning the API connection.

Comment: It's been a while since I've followed up - but I am now stuck on another portion of the API.  I will ask that in a separate question, I believe.  Right now - I would like to know how to translate or effectively read what type of data I am getting back from the API so I can tackle other return results from the API in my code.  For example, there is a return called MultipleMatches.  In it the API apparently "suggests" more addresses that may match, I want to be able to display those but my efforts are futile.  How do I understand the Reference and WSDL better?

Comment: What data the service returns (and how to use it) is probably best directed to CDYNE.  All Visual Studio does when you add a service reference is generate proxy classes from the WSDL so you get strongly typed objects (and intellisense).